# NPM got downgraded and now I cant use it anymore

Tags: node.js, npm

I entered this line in my laravel project because it was offered as a solution

```
npm i -g npm@3.10.10
```

Then when i tried to use npm again this showed up:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.18362
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\mehme_x44gbsl\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v15.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\npm-debug.log
```

I tried reinstalling nodejs but the npm file was the same.

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` try this.

Comment: It didn't do anything, please help me i need to finish project in 2 days...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank god I found this solution.

1. Follow this directory:

   ```
   C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming
   ```
2. Delete the npm folder.
3. Run the following command:

   ```
   npm clean cache —force
   ```
4. Then run:

   ```
   npm install
   ```

and now my npm is updated